# Add name attribute to what gets emitted from a view in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have a really simple emit statement in a view.

```
emit([doc.salesDate, doc.companyId], doc.grossSales);
```

Is there any way I can make the JSON object it returns show up like this

```
{
    "grossSales" : "100"
}
```

instead of

```
{
    0: "100"
}
```

EDIT: I'm using the rest API if it makes a difference

Comment: What is  `doc.grossSales`? Can you give a sample doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you want the view to be as lightweight as possible but you can do this by simply emitting a JSON object

```
emit([doc.salesDate, doc.companyId], {"grossSales": doc.grossSales});
```

This assumes the document looks like this:

```
{
   "salesDate": "2015-06-13T00:27:55.511Z",
   "companyId": "Couchbase",
   "grossSales": 100
}
```

The output from the REST API:

```
{"total_rows":1,"rows":[
{"id":"test","key":["2015-06-13T00:27:55.511Z","Couchbase"],"value":{"grossSales":100}}
]
}
```

Please note that the REST API for views should only be used for testing and debug. In a production environment a SDK should be used.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thanks! The couch base documentation isnt the greatest and I couldn't find anything about this.